# I want to print current year last month date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle, what I want to print is current year last month record in Oracle.

Expected Output: `201707`

The following works in SQL Server and I need to get the same in Oracle

```
select convert(varchar(10),year(GETDATE())) + '0' + convert(varchar(10), MONTH(getdate())-1)
```

Comment: Above query is working in SQL, I want same output in oracle

Comment: I understand what you meant. My apology!!!. Above query I wrote in MS SQL 2012

Comment: Obviously, "current year last month" doesn't make sense on 20 January, since "last moth" then is not in the "current" year. Please clarify.

Comment: I did not thought about it previously, but I think you are right. How can I tackle this situation any idea???

Comment: Now you are asking the right question, but the wrong person. If this is a business problem, ask the users who asked for a solution in the first place. What do THEY need this for, and how do THEY need to handle January. If it is homework, ask the teacher what he or she wants for January. (You may get a high grade just for asking the question!) The developer is not the one to decide how to handle logical inconsistencies in the problem requirement; that is for the people who made the request in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You code appears to be for SQL Server (and not Oracle).

Apart from that, getting the year and month components and subtracting one from the month will not work when the current month is January as you would get the month output as `00`.

This should work:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), -1 ), 'YYYYMM' )
FROM   DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

@MT0 has provided a correct answer already.

It can be simplified in either of the following two ways:

```
select to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'yyyymm') from dual;
```

or

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1, 'yyyymm') from dual;
```

The point being: if you use `add_months` (with the argument -1 to go back one month) then there is no need to truncate `sysdate` first; it can be used as is. Alternatively, if you go to the trouble of truncating `sysdate` first, then you can just subtract one day, no need to subtract a whole month. Either way, one function call should suffice, no need for two function calls (before applying `to_char()` to the result).

Answer (score -2):

Different ways to achieve this.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-31,'YYYYMM') FROM   DUAL;
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')-1 FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'YYYYMM') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-31,'YYYYMM')` fails for most 1st day of Month. `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')-1` fails on January